# How to push schema to Apicurio schema registry without any cdc event/records using Debezium

Tags: schema, avro, debezium, change-data-capture, apicurio-registry

**Usecase**: I need my all schemas for all tables in sql database to be present in apicurio registry without having any cdc records in cdc tables using Debezium.

Currently, schema is pushed to Apicurio for only those table on which CDC is enabled and if any of their record is updated.

**Requirement**: Is there any way to push all schemas of all cdc enabled tables to Apicurio without cdc events or without modifying any record of any table?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Apicurio has a [REST API](https://www.apicur.io/registry/docs/apicurio-registry/2.3.x/getting-started/assembly-managing-registry-artifacts-api.html) you could use in order to Create/Read/Update/Delete schemas. Hope it helps. Note that schemas should be compatible with the schemas generated by Debezium if you want Debezium to use those, otherwise, it will fail.

Comment: But I don't have schema to push, I want debezium to push schema generated by it for all the tables whose corresponding CDC tables doesn't have any record (Basically no record level updation is done)